# How to get the width and height attributes from the image tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have the following image tag

```
<img class="someclass" src="somesrc" width="220" height="165" />
```

The browser is displaying the image with its original width and height which is `480x360`

I want to get the image width and height attributes from the image tag which should return `220 and 165`

I have tried the following

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('someclass');
console.log(img.clientWidth);
console.log($('.someclass').attr('width'));
```

But it returns me `undefined`.

The following code returns me the actual width and height of the image. which is 480

```
$('.someclass').width();
```

Is there any way that it should return the `220 and 165`?

Comment: `img` is `HTMLCollection`, not an element

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0]`

Comment: `$('.someclass').attr('width')` should've worked fine

Comment: Why is image an html collection? Just curious.

Comment: @adeneo: [And does.](https://jsfiddle.net/j6kkh18w/) :-)

Comment: @VSO - `getElementsByClassName` returns a **nodeList**, not a single element

Comment: @adeneo Alright, thanks.

Comment: @VSO: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Comment: @VSO - `getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements, hence get Element**s** :)

Comment: hope you are including jquery. it should work without any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for your help. But I have found the solution.
The following code works for me.

```
$('img.someclass).load(function(){
  var width = $(this).attr('width');
  var height = $(this).attr('height');
  if(width != 'undefined') {
     $(this).css('width', width);
  }
  if(height != 'undefined') {
    $(this).css('height', height);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the width attribute of a single element not a nodeList as you were returning.

Try this...

```
var element = document.querySelector('.someclass');
console.log(element.getAttribute('width')); //220
console.log(element.getAttribute('height')); //165
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0];
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height
```

and in case you want to set new values just do:

```
img.width = yourvalue;
img.height = yourvalue;
```

it works fine, so plz don't downvote people for no reason

Comment: You misread the question he is after the attribute value not the rendered width / height